# d3.js reset positon of viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I use dagre and d3 to display graphs. The graph elements and the viewport can be dragged, and zoomed. After dragging/zooming the viewport whenever I redraw the graph (or draw another graph) the viewport stays where it was set previously, but resets on first interaction (jumps to [0,0], and default zoom ratio).

How to reset position of the viewport in d3 with function call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dagre author here - are you using the dagre demo or is this custom code? If you're using the dagre demo, I can confirm the behavior you're observing and the fix is to add this line:

`svgGroup.attr("transform", "translate(5, 5)");`

before this code block (dagre/demo.js, line 252 in my tree):

```
svg.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function redraw() {
    svgGroup.attr("transform",
          "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")"
          + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}));
```

I've updated the demo in the source code under this ticket: https://github.com/cpettitt/dagre/issues/56

Thanks!

Comment: hey Chris, can you take a peak on this question? I'd appreciate any help! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26636878/position-of-a-custom-shape-using-dagre